# Manipulating Probabilities to Sum to a Fixed Value for Each Group with Capping Constraints

Tags: r

There’s a model which generates estimated probabilities that an outcome will occur to a particular person who is competing in an event. The outcome is guaranteed to occur exactly 3 times per event.

The model’s estimates look like the following, although in real life there are a lot more events and also more persons within each event.

```
data <- data.frame(event_id = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003), outcome_probability = c(0.001, 0.102, 0.3, 0.288, 0.3, 0.007, 0.002, 0.002, 0.004, 0.6, 0.3, 0.35, 0.244))
```

I need to manipulate the probabilities so they sum to 3 for each event.

In the case of event 1001 it’s easy to work out what needs to be done. The total estimated probabilities sum to 1, and so multiplying each probability by 3 works and then the total estimated probabilities for event 1001 will sum to 3 like they should.

For event 1003 it’s not so simple. The total summed probabilities add up to 1.5. Multiplying the probabilities in event 1003 by 2 will “work” in the sense that it’ll leave a total summed probability of 3 for the event, as it should. However, person 10 would then have an estimated probability of 1.2 which is not allowed. What I’d want to do in such situations is to cap the maximum probability at 0.99.

Can anyone advise as to how I could do this in R?

By the way, although it isn’t depicted above, in some events the total summed probabilities for an event will already be larger than 3, and so will need to be reduced rather than increased.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the probabilities represent? There are many ways to adjust the probabilities so they sum to 3 by event, but I doubt many of those ways would make sense.

Comment: There's a sporting event where for each match the best 3 players (as judged subjectively by a panel) are given a special award. Ultimately the goal is to adjust the probabilities so that they sum to 3 for each event (and hence are appropriately calibrated, since there will be 3 awards for each event). The method suggested in text is a bit of a simplification - actually something like Laplace smoothing will be used to further adjust the probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do.

```
prob_adj <- function(x, a=3, tol=1e-8) {
  Z0 <- sum(x)
  f <- a/Z0
  x1 <- x*f
  if (any(cap <- x1 >= 1)) {
    x1[cap] <- 1 - tol
    Z1 <- sum(x1)
    adjust_f <- (a - sum(x1[cap])) / 
      (Z1 - sum(x1[cap]))
    x1[!cap] <- x1[!cap]*adjust_f
  }
  return(x1)
}


(data <- transform(data, outcome_probability3=ave(outcome_probability, event_id, FUN=prob_adj)))
#    event_id outcome_probability outcome_probability3
# 1      1001               0.001          0.003006012
# 2      1001               0.102          0.306613226
# 3      1001               0.300          0.901803607
# 4      1001               0.288          0.865731463
# 5      1001               0.300          0.901803607
# 6      1001               0.007          0.021042084
# 7      1003               0.002          0.004434590
# 8      1003               0.002          0.004434590
# 9      1003               0.004          0.008869180
# 10     1003               0.600          0.999999990
# 11     1003               0.300          0.665188473
# 12     1003               0.350          0.776053219
# 13     1003               0.244          0.541019958
```

*Proof:*

```
tapply(data$outcome_probability3, data$event_id, sum)
# 1001 1003 
#    3    3
```

Other data (from comments):

```
prob_adj(probs) |> {\(x) c(sum=sum(x), range=toString(range(x)))}()
# sum                              range 
# "3" "2.14946165861397e-05, 0.99999999"
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(event_id = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 
1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003), outcome_probability = c(0.001, 
0.102, 0.3, 0.288, 0.3, 0.007, 0.002, 0.002, 0.004, 0.6, 0.3, 
0.35, 0.244), outcome_probability3 = c(0.0030060120240481, 0.306613226452906, 
0.901803607214429, 0.865731462925852, 0.901803607214429, 0.0210420841683367, 
0.00399467376830892, 0.00399467376830892, 0.00798934753661784, 
1.19840213049268, 0.599201065246338, 0.699067909454061, 0.487350199733688
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

probs <- c(0.015003864, 1.65e-05, 0.909154208, 0.009505759, 0.003737031, 
0.000202459, 6.19e-05, 0.007947804, 3.81e-05, 0.000146555, 0.154014922, 
0.021845128, 0.057272665, 0.023091625, 0.001444357, 0.019820499, 
0.000741997, 8.89e-06, 0.049531917, 0.003559092, 0.000234366, 
0.157857522, 0.000701634, 0.016473648, 0.002520932, 0.006923765, 
0.015803802, 0.000546999, 0.00571661, 0.030888464, 0.00011889, 
0.060128612, 0.004648332, 0.000451678, 0.000324167, 0.069204394, 
0.001446103, 0.000533095, 0.047108026, 7.13e-05, 0.014174826, 
0.01124186, 0.007812016, 0.000246929, 0.000716656, 0.003298178
```

Comment: This is elegant but I think it violates the "no probabilities above .99 allowed" rule with regard to Person 10? Ultimately the output needs to have person-level probabilities above .99, and all event-level probabilities summing to 3.

Comment: @Слава-Україні I see, but if it's capped, the sum is no longer 3, what do you wantr in this case?

Comment: The idea would be to cap (if necessary) a particular person or persons at 0.99, and then adjust everyone else so that the total sum for the event comes to 3. Apologies for any lack of clarity in the initial post.

Comment: @Слава-Україні OK. See update.

Comment: `probs <- c(0.015003864, 1.65E-05, 0.909154208, 0.009505759, 0.003737031, 0.000202459, 6.19E-05, 0.007947804, 3.81E-05, 0.000146555, 0.154014922, 0.021845128, 0.057272665, 0.023091625, 0.001444357, 0.019820499, 0.000741997, 8.89E-06, 0.049531917, 0.003559092, 0.000234366, 0.157857522, 0.000701634, 0.016473648, 0.002520932, 0.006923765, 0.015803802, 0.000546999, 0.00571661, 0.030888464, 0.00011889, 0.060128612, 0.004648332, 0.000451678, 0.000324167, 0.069204394, 0.001446103, 0.000533095, 0.047108026, 7.13E-05, 0.014174826, 0.01124186, 0.007812016, 0.000246929, 0.000716656, 0.003298178)`

Comment: That's some of my actual data. If I go `data <- data.frame(event_id = rep(16508, length(probs)), outcome_probability = probs)` and then run your code I find someone with an outcome probability of 1.166409. Have I misapplied something somewhere?

Comment: @user1205901-СлаваУкраїні See update.